# Custom action after Rasa response selection

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, sentiment-analysis, rasa

I have a working Rasa chatbot that can utter responses based on a story. For some utterances, there are multiple options, and everything works as it should.

However, I want to be able to perform sentiment analysis based on the bot's chosen response.

So my question is how do I perform a custom action after Rasa has selected the response?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [custom action](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/actions/) that is run after that bot's response. A custom action has access to the current conversation's tracker which includes the bot's previous response.